# getElementById after dynamically adding it in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state, use-ref

I am adding Cards dynamically in my React functional component. Cards are stored in State. I map them and give id to each of them. OnClick on those Cards I get their id successfully. Now I want to getElementById to change Card color:

```
function Clicked(pressedGifId) {
  if (pressedGifId === 'correctGif') CorrectMatch();
  else WrongMatch();
}

function CorrectMatch(pressedGifId) {
  // / THERE I GET Element: null
  console.log('Element:', document.getElementById(pressedGifId));
}
function WrongMatch() {
  console.log('wrong a match!');
}

export default function GameObject(props) {
  const addedToGameGif = [];
  const [pressedGifId, gifPressed] = useState(null);
  const [photoCards, setPhotoCards] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    Clicked(pressedGifId);
  }, [pressedGifId]);

  // add randomly picked photos to addedToGameGif array
  // ...

  addedToGameGif.map(gifId =>
    photoCards.push(
      <Card id={gifId} onClick={() => gifPressed(gifId)}>
        text
      </Card>,
    ),
  );

  return <div>{photoCards}</div>;
}
```

I tried learning refs but they are only for class components. So how do I reach my element by id in React?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ref` in functional component as well. There is a hook called `useRef`.

> Note: Never interact directly with `DOM` until or unless there is no api available in react to solve the problem for that particular use case.
>
> In react it's not recommended to interact directly with dom. Always use react apis to interact with dom. React is designed to hide the DOM because they want to abstract the DOM away. By using the DOM directly you break the abstraction and make your code brittle to changes introduced in the library.
>
> React is maintaining a virtual `DOM` if we make any changes in actual `DOM`  directly then `react` will not be aware of this change and this can lead to some unexpected behavior .

```
import React, {useState, useRef} from 'react';

export default function GameObject(props) {
  const addedToGameGif = [];
  const [pressedGifId, gifPressed] = useState(null);
  const [photoCards, setPhotoCards] = useState([]);
  const elemRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    Clicked(pressedGifId);
  }, [pressedGifId]);

  // add randomly picked photos to addedToGameGif array
  // ...

  addedToGameGif.map(gifId =>
    photoCards.push(
      <Card ref={elemRef} id={gifId} onClick={() => gifPressed(gifId)}>
        text
      </Card>
    )
  );

  return <div>{photoCards}</div>;
}
```

**Example from official docs.**

```
function TextInputWithFocusButton() {
  const inputEl = useRef(null);
  const onButtonClick = () => {
    // `current` points to the mounted text input element
    inputEl.current.focus();
  };
  return (
    <>
      <input ref={inputEl} type="text" />
      <button onClick={onButtonClick}>Focus the input</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: That was a stupid mistake of mine: I just havent passed pressedGifId to CorrectMatch function previously.... But getElementById surprisingly works perfectly now. Are there some cons why I should use refs instead of simple getElementById ?

Comment: In react it's not recommended to interact directly with dom. Always use react apis to interact with dom. 

React is designed to hide the DOM because they want to abstract the DOM away. 
By using the DOM directly you break the abstraction and make your code brittle to changes introduced in the library.

Comment: One more thing to note, React is maintaining a virtual `DOM` if we make any changes in actual `DOM`  directly then `react` will not be aware of this change and this can lead to some unexpected behavior .